# How to determine the rated voltage for 3 phase motor

Tags: voltage, motor

I have an unlabeled 3 phase motor (based on the size probably 5 HP) with 3 pairs of wires and a schematic picture for wye and delta connections. Since there’s no label I have no idea what the rated voltage is. I tried to run it with a 240V VFD at 60Hz base frequency and it makes an unhappy noise and the VFD trips.

I suspect it is a 480V motor. How can I determine the rated voltage for this motor?

Comment: I suspect it's a 120V and/or 400Hz motor. Because saturation is the only thing that can cause overcurrent besides mechanical load, and saturation happens because the applied voltage divided by frequency is too high.

Comment: Wow, you seem to be correct and you’re pointing in the right direction - increasing the base frequency has helped, I was able to run it smoothly at 240v 110Hz. This surprises me a lot because this is a large industrial motor mounted on lathe and these large motors are all 60hz and larger they get the higher the rated voltage is. Based on the size alone (weighs probably 80 lb) I would not think the voltage is any less than 240v.  I suppose I can play with VFD and measure the amperage and rotation speed and finally come with optimal parameters... I wish there was a more elegant way to calculate

Comment: If 240V 110Hz is okay, 120V 60Hz will function as well. 120V motors come at any size, just as 240V motors.

Comment: Impossible. This is a large 5 hp industrial lathe, industrial power supply is 3 phase 240-480v. I’ve never seen 5 HP 3 phase motor for 120v. Perhaps custom made 200v. Is there a scientific way to calculate the voltage?

Comment: It's that quotient. Voltage divided by frequency. It's constant for a given machine. That one is proportional to the flux the machine allows which depends on the amount of iron it has per winding.

Comment: Thank you. I found the manufacturer and looked it up based on its serial number - this motor is Lincoln 5hp, 3ph, 60hz, 200v